# Как поменять тип поля связанной модели?

Tags: python, django, django-model

Есть две модели: PurchaseList с полем recipe, которое является ForeignKey и строит связь с моделью Recipe:

```
class PurchaseList(models.Model):
"""Модель списка рецептов."""

author = models.ForeignKey('User',
                           on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                           verbose_name='Автор',
                           related_name='added_to_cart')
recipe = models.ForeignKey('Recipe',
                           on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                           verbose_name='Рецепт',
                           related_name='is_in_shopping_cart')

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Список покупок'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Списки покупок'
    ordering = ['recipes']

def __str__(self):
    return self.recipe
```

Вторая модель Recipe выглядит так:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
"""Модель отдельно взятого рецепта."""

tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, verbose_name='Теги')
author = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='recipes',
                           on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор')
ingridients = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='IngredientToRecipe',
                                     verbose_name='Ингредиент')
name = models.CharField(max_length=16, verbose_name='Наименование')
image = models.ImageField(
    upload_to='recipes/images/',
    default=None,
    verbose_name='Изображение'
)
text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание')
cooking_time = models.IntegerField(
    verbose_name='Время приготовления в минутах')
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                verbose_name='Дата публикации')

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Рецепт'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Рецепты'
    ordering = ['-pub_date']

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Документация требует, чтобы поле 'is_in_shopping_cart' модели Recipe имело формат BooleanField.
Таким образом, у меня возникает вопрос - как определить формат поля, образованного из связанной модели, в основной модели?

Comment: Чтобы определить формат поля, образованного из связанной модели в основной модели, необходимо использовать параметр `field` отношения. В данном случае отношение recipe уже определено как `ForeignKey`. Чтобы изменить его формат, достаточно передать объект `BooleanField` свойству `field` отношения.

Comment: Получается, добавление параметра field в таком виде решает проблему?

```recipe = models.ForeignKey('Recipe', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Рецепт', related_name='is_in_shopping_cart', field = models.BooleanField())```
Просто я не нашел такого свойства в документации, из похожего только to_field, но оно тут не нужно.

Comment: Я подумал, может быть стоит оставить модель PurchaseList без изменений и решить проблему, добавив следующий метод в модель Recipe:

```@property```
```def is_in_shopping_cart(self):```
    ```return PurchaseList.objects.filter(author=self.author).exists()```

Как вы думаете, такое решение может помочь?